# Launch 2 windows shell from a bat

Tags: windows, shell, selenium, selenium-grid

i'm using selenium grid and i want to launch the hub and the node from a bat file, i have tried doing it like this :

> java -jar "c:\selenium-2.53.0\selenium-server-standalone-2.53.0.jar" -port 4444 -role hub -nodeTimeout 1000
>
> java -jar "C:\selenium-2.53.0\selenium-server-standalone-2.53.0.jar" -role node -hub http://localhost:4444/grid/register -browser browserName=firefox -port 5555

But the problem is that when the shell execute the first command he wait that this command end before runing another one. The thing is that the command don't end until i close the hub so he never run the node command.

I've found a solution where the i had to call another bat file in the main bat file.

Is there another way to it ?
Thanks

Comment: what are you trying to do by launching 2 windows??

Comment: i don't want to launch 2 windows but 2 windows shell.

Comment: Same question, what do you want to do launching 2 shell? is the selenium tag relative?

Comment: I have one shell for the hub, and one shell for the node, i can't run them in the same shell.

Comment: it's like if i had to run two ping command that never stop at the same time, i need 2 shells to do this, i put the selenium tag because i guess there is other ppl using selenium grid that already had encounter this problem

Comment: Try with `start java -jar "c:\selenium-2.53.0\selenium-server-standalone-2.53.0.jar" -port 4444 -role hub -nodeTimeout 1000`

Comment: ty it's working, i though start command was only used to start a program and not another command

Answer (score 0):

I could do what i wanted by using the start instruction :

> start java -jar "c:\selenium-2.53.0\selenium-server-standalone-2.53.0.jar" -port 4444 -role hub -nodeTimeout 1000
>
> start java -jar "C:\selenium-2.53.0\selenium-server-standalone-2.53.0.jar" -role node -hub http://localhost:4444/grid/register -browser browserName=firefox -port 5555

As it was suggested by Florent B. in the answer of the original post.